# Meteor CORS android 4.1.2

Tags: meteor

I'm getting this error when I try to upload a file using android 4.1.2:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://bucket.storage.aws.net/. Origin http://meteor.local is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

The application works perfectly on android 4.4+. Does anyone know how to fix this problem for older versions of android? 
Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever work this out? I may be having the same problem